# Collapsing Toolbar is not scrollable

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I‘m trying to create an app containing a collapsing toolbar. Below is the layout of my XML file. The intention was to make it collapsing but with my code everything is just fixed to its current position and not scrollable at all. Hope anyone has any suggestions. 
As information: I’m using android studio and the system runs at API 26

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.te.e5.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/coltoolbar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="App Title"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:background="@drawable/materialbackground">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: is it collapsing upon dragging up ??

Comment: You need to scroll toolbar too?

Comment: It should be scrollable and end up in the toolbar, or what do you mean?

Comment: i tested your code ..the CollapsingToolbarLayout work well @user9155899...its not fixed..just pull it down..and up

Comment: @user9155899 i have updated my answer please check..

Comment: @ALTegani You sure? Doesn‘t work for me actually

Comment: yes very sure...i just changed the background image from yours to mine its maybe caused the fixed..or you didnt pull it down well?!..@user9155899

Comment: @user9155899 Same here its work on my side too. Even I just changed the drawable.

Comment: Okay thanks so far, but why doesn‘t my Emulator do it properly?

Comment: Have you checked it in physical device?

Answer (score 0):

Change the flags sequence in CollapsingToolbarLayout like this

```
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

if you want the collapsing toolbar to scroll when user scrolls content then the first flag should be "scroll" always then "exitUntilCollapsed".

Solution:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.birjuvachhani.myapplication.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <!-- Main content goes here. -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how.why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.